# Ansible Repo - structure

Tags: git, ansible

The suggested repo by Ansible can be seen at:- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html

```
production                # inventory file for production servers
staging                   # inventory file for staging environment

group_vars/
   group1                 # here we assign variables to particular groups
   group2                 # ""
host_vars/
   hostname1              # if systems need specific variables, put them here
   hostname2              # ""

library/                  # if any custom modules, put them here (optional)
filter_plugins/           # if any custom filter plugins, put them here (optional)

site.yml                  # master playbook
webservers.yml            # playbook for webserver tier
dbservers.yml             # playbook for dbserver tier

roles/
    common/               # this hierarchy represents a "role"
        tasks/            #
            main.yml      #  <-- tasks file can include smaller files if warranted
        handlers/         #
            main.yml      #  <-- handlers file
        templates/        #  <-- files for use with the template resource
            ntp.conf.j2   #  <------- templates end in .j2
        files/            #
            bar.txt       #  <-- files for use with the copy resource
            foo.sh        #  <-- script files for use with the script resource
        vars/             #
            main.yml      #  <-- variables associated with this role
        defaults/         #
            main.yml      #  <-- default lower priority variables for this role
        meta/             #
            main.yml      #  <-- role dependencies

    webtier/              # same kind of structure as "common" was above, done for the webtier role
    monitoring/           # ""
    fooapp/               # ""
```

My question is about what level this repo sits at - do you have one of these formats for each project/app or is this for the whole estate?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take a hybrid approach. Each team/project gets their own space but I maintain a global inventory and set of group_vars related to the network and datacenter infrastructure.

Ansible is flexible, so start simple and mold it to your particular teams and the way your company works.

Comment: I think we are moving towards that direction - does that mean that inside a team repo you are getting a load of different files like appname_site.yml, appname1_servers, appname2_servers?

Comment: Different sites and app lifecycles I recommend folks differentiate through the use of different playbooks. I take care of making sure the servers are all tagged with application, datacenter, lifecycle, and role. Using the intersection of these tags they're able to define the list of hosts they want to go after with their playbooks. So yes, lots of playbooks for my teams, but no inventory.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your preference and/or the size/complexity of your projects. I think it makes perfect sense to have projects separated in different repositories.

If you have common roles used by multiple projects, you can use git submodules (painful if you do work with branches/forks) or [Ansible Galaxy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#advanced-control-over-role-requirements-files) to install those from another repo.